# Issues turning dapper query into a list

Tags: c#, linq, dapper

All I'm trying to do is turn a dapper query into a list of dictionaries where the keys are the column names and the values are the row values. However, I'm not getting what I want from my code.

My imports:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Linq;
using Dapper;
```

The query code:

```
            using (var dbContext = await SqlServerRepository.OpenConnection())
            {
                string sql = @"SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(DateSearch) YearValue
                               FROM KeySearch
                               ORDER BY YearValue;";
                var result = (await dbContext.QueryAsync(sql)).ToList();
                ViewBag.Years = new SelectList(result, "YearValue", "YearValue");
            }
```

I get a list of `dapperrow` objects instead of the dictionary.

[image]

I've tried setting the type using `QueryAsync<Dictionary<string,object>>(sql)` but this returns a list of empty dictionaries.

[image]

I also tried `result.Select(row => (IDictionary<string, object>)row).ToList()` but it returned the same list of dapperrows.

Comment: @YongShun I didn't think I'd need that, that's why my original code doesn't have it. But it doesn't work either way.

Comment: From [DapperRow](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/136dc11f0cd1fbab1e23fedbd58d29ca141bfd7d/Dapper/SqlMapper.DapperRow.cs#L11), it implements `IDictionary<string, object>`, by right you should able to get the data correctly. I more concerned on passing `List<IDictionary<string, object>>` to `SelectList` will work.

Answer (score 2):

DapperRow [is already IDictionary<string, object>](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/136dc11f0cd1fbab1e23fedbd58d29ca141bfd7d/Dapper/SqlMapper.DapperRow.cs#L10) by itself, so you can use it as dictionary right away. The type and description in the debugger is just a red-herring.

Noted that `QueryAsync` returns list of `dynamic` by definition, so it is possible that `QueryAsync` might not return dictionary type in the future, but I think it is very unlikely to happen.

Comment: Could be. I solved it by just creating a class and specifying the type.